# How realistic is it that a Russian agent would be working at Space Force?

Tags: space-force

In *Space Force* (the Netflix series) we see that Yuri, who is a Russian agent (astronaut? scientist?) officially works at Space Force, with a fairly high-level access, as he is able to simply walk in General Naird's office without being stopped by security.

We see at some point that there are ESA (European Space Agency) members working in collaboration with SF, which isn't too far-fetched as a lot of European countries are NATO members and allies of the US.

I know SF isn't the most realistic show, especially regarding who does what, like Naird going away to moon camp for a week on a whim, or Cpt Ali being put in charge of the moon mission when she isn't even an astronaut (yet). But is there any reason that a Russian agent would be (officially) given such access to an American military agency?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right site to ask, but it didn't seem to fit space.stackexchange, as it is related to a fictional show. Feel free to edit tags, as I wasn't able to create new ones (like 'space-force')

Comment: I've not watched the show, but I don't think there's anything in there that classifies it as science fiction *or* fantasy. You'd have to ask on [movies.se].

Comment: There are certain fantastical elements of the show. Such as the Chinese Space Station flying over and clipping off the solar arrays of the new satellite, and then them convincing a chimpanzee to do the repairs.

Comment: Considering it is set in the near future and China has a spaceship capable of dismantling other satellites and a moonbase complete with drilling station, doesn't it qualifies as science-fiction ?

Comment: Great, now the question is closed because people who haven't watched the show assume it isn't science-fictional...

Comment: I've voted to reopen now, I was going off of third party information that wasn't entirely accurate so sorry for that. The information in the comments here is enough to make it on topic for me.

Comment: @ThePainfull IMHO (having watched it all) It's not a sci-fi show per se although it does have rockets and space  and moonbases in it .  And I think there is going to be some lively debate in the near future as to what constitutes sci-fi.  EG a story in the 1940's that made heavy use of a global handheld personal communicator network would have been called sci-fi, but in 2020 cellphone usage is "meh".  And was the James Bond Moonraker movie sci-fi?  And will the purported Tom Cruise In Space movie be sci-fi?

Comment: @PeterM You live on a [Spaceship](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/497929302523020305/)

Answer (score 5):

According to Wikipedia, he is designated as a liaison from the Russian Space Force working along side the US Space Force - [citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Force_(TV_series)#Recurring). Foreign Liaison Officer is real thing, where cooperative countries will exchange officers for the purpose of collaboration and coalition building.

With NASA's reliance on Russia for IIS access for the last 10 years, it is certainly believable that they have a friendly relationship, at least with the Russian Space Agency.

Comment: In the context of NASA, it would make perfect sense, but Space Force is a separate entity, and a military one at that. I don't think Russia and the US cooperate on a military level (although i could be wrong)

Comment: They work together on lots of things, despite political differences. https://www.americansecurityproject.org/us-russia-relationship/us-russia-cooperation/